# Ways to round a float number with the 0.5 rule

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point, rounding

I can't achieve rounding a float with the common 0.5 rule.
Let's be precise... How may I make such rounds :

- x.x2 -> x.x
- x.x5 -> x.x (or x.x+1 would be good also)
- x.x6 -> x.x+1

So for example :

- 1.12 -> 1.1
- 1.22 -> 1.2
- 1.15 -> 1.1 (or 1.2 woudl be good also)
- 1.25 -> 1.2 (or 1.3 woudl be good also)
- 1.16 -> 1.2
- 1.26 -> 1.3

I tried those methods (perhaps in a wrong way) :

- NSNumberFormatter
- NSDecimalNumber
- ...

But nothing can give that result. I always get some x.x99999999 results, or badly rounded ones (too high, to low, or on even numbers when the rounded number should come on the upper one).

Comment: Since you mention `x.x99999999` results, you could try using the `%.1f` formatter to `printf`.

Comment: What Mike said; it sounds like the classic "floating-point numbers are in base-2 not base-10" issue.

Comment: BTW, "even numbers when the rounded number should come on the upper one" is the usual way it's done so that rounding doesn't throw in a small positive shift to the average of a series of numbers. (E.g. since x = 0.0 doesn't round, 0.0 < x < 0.5 rounds down to 0, and 0.5 < x < 1.0 rounds up to 1, the average after rounding of the x != 0.5 cases is 0.5. If x = 0.5 always rounds to 1.0, then the average is 0.5 + epsilon, where epsilon is small. Rounding to the nearest even number removes this epsilon.)

Comment: @Mike DeSimone : That's right, but this is not the common way it's done in big systems as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
round(x * 10.0f) / 10.0f
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overflow in [@junjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810933/2410359)'s good answer, only manipulate `x` when it has a fractional part.

```
float round_tenth(float x) {

  const float limit = 1.0/FLT_EPSILON;
  // or limit = FLT_MAX/10.0;

  if (fabsf(x) < limit) {
    return roundf(x*10.0f)/10.0f;
  }
  return x;
}
```